# Ubuntu 14.10 Restarting Randomly

Tags: 14.10, restart

I just installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my external HD and everything works just fine (I haven't made any changes to the system files yet), but after a little while (I don't know how long, sometimes it's 15 min, sometimes 30 min) Ubuntu restarts on its own (no, I didn't have many processes running at the same time, most times I was just copying a file or watching a video on youtube)

I've already researched this but haven't found a solution yet and I don't know what I have to specify, since I'm new to Ubuntu...

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you provide the research you've already done so we don't try things you've already tried? ;-)

Comment: Also check the **syslog** for that time, there is always some important info in there.

Comment: how do I do that?
(btw, I haven't found any info yet)
Here's my hw:
Memory: 6.7 GiB
Processor: 410 APU 410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics AMD A8-6410 APU with AMD Radeon R5 Graphics × 3 
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD MULLINS
OS type: 64-bit
Disk: 97.6 GB

Comment: I got something form dmesg:
[   24.964475] systemd-logind[973]: Failed to start unit user@112.service: Unknown unit: user@112.service
[   24.964486] systemd-logind[973]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@112.service
[   24.971079] systemd-logind[973]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
[   24.971116] systemd-logind[973]: Linked /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 to /run/user/112/X11-display.
[   37.854929] systemd-logind[973]: Failed to start unit user@1000.service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service
[   37.854945] systemd-logind[973]: Failed to start user service: Unknown unit: user@1000.service

Comment: here's the link with the full output:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByLU2bCAP7UdLUVqbzFOQ2owaHc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can check the syslog by entering this command in your terminal:

```
less /var/log/syslog
```

or, if you want to explore the result in your favorite text editor (Geany in this example) :

```
geany /var/log/syslog
```

(but you'll have to save the result elsewhere).

dmesg returns me the same message `(systemd-logind[1114]: Failed to start unit user@112.service: Unknown unit: user@112.service)`, but I don't have  Ubuntu restarting on its own, so I suppose it will be unnecessary to search in this direction...